openapi-generator-maven-plugin not generating implementation code
Around 4-5 years ago I set up a number of microservices for a client. These used Swagger and then later OpenAPI to define the services. I used the Maven openapi-generator-maven-plugin to generate the API, model and implementation code.
I'm now trying to set up a similar process for another client and I cannot get it to create the implementation code as I remember it.
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>7.4.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>portal-api</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>
                    ${project.parent.basedir}/openapi/model.yaml</inputSpec>
                <generatorName>jaxrs-cxf</generatorName>
                <generateSupportingFiles>true</generateSupportingFiles>
                <configOptions>
                    <implFolder>src/main/java</implFolder>
                    <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                    <sourceFolder>src/gen/java</sourceFolder>
                    <useGenericResponse>true</useGenericResponse>
                    <useLoggingFeature>true</useLoggingFeature>
                    <addConsumesProducesJson>true</addConsumesProducesJson>
                    <useAnnotatedBasePath>true</useAnnotatedBasePath>
                </configOptions>
                <output>${project.build.directory}</output>
                <apiPackage>portal.menu.rest.api</apiPackage>
                <modelPackage>portal.menu.rest.api.model</modelPackage>
                <invokerPackage>portal.menu.rest.impl</invokerPackage>
                <verbose>false</verbose>
                <ignoreFileOverride>${project.basedir}/.openapi-generator-ignore</ignoreFileOverride>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

The console output:
[INFO] Processing operation getAllApplications
[INFO] writing file C:\Users\paul\eclipse-workspace\portal.menu.parent\portal.menu.rest\target\src\gen\java\portal\menu\rest\api\model\Application.java
[INFO] writing file C:\Users\paul\eclipse-workspace\portal.menu.parent\portal.menu.rest\target\src\main\java\portal\menu\rest\api\impl\ApplicationApiServiceImpl.java
[INFO] writing file C:\Users\paul\eclipse-workspace\portal.menu.parent\portal.menu.rest\target\src\gen\java\portal\menu\rest\api\ApplicationApi.java
[INFO] Skipped C:\Users\paul\eclipse-workspace\portal.menu.parent\portal.menu.rest\target\src\test\java\portal\menu\rest\api\ApplicationApiTest.java (Test files never overwrite an existing file of the same name.)
[INFO] Skipping generation of Webhooks.
[INFO] writing file C:\Users\paul\eclipse-workspace\portal.menu.parent\portal.menu.rest\target\pom.xml
[INFO] writing file C:\Users\paul\eclipse-workspace\portal.menu.parent\portal.menu.rest\target\.openapi-generator-ignore
[INFO] Skipped C:\Users\paul\eclipse-workspace\portal.menu.parent\portal.menu.rest\target\.openapi-generator-ignore (Skipped by supportingFiles options supplied by user.)
[INFO] writing file C:\Users\paul\eclipse-workspace\portal.menu.parent\portal.menu.rest\target\.openapi-generator\VERSION
[INFO] writing file C:\Users\paul\eclipse-workspace\portal.menu.parent\portal.menu.rest\target\.openapi-generator\FILES

I expect a sample implementation class to be generated in the src section and an ignore to be created in the project root so that the implementation stub will only be created once.
Am I doing something wrong? Am I remembering it wrong? Has the feature been removed?

Hi I have also used similar thing recently. Only difference which I can observe from top of my head here is I used generatorName as jaxrs-spec
Also see if this helps: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin/README.md
